# Como restar primer valor con ultimo valor en array [PHP]

Tags: php, html, array

Estoy comenzando con PHP y tengo que hacer este ejercicio:
Como dato no puedo usar funciones de php

El ejercicio consiste en ingresar un numero a traves de un formulario, este numero indica la longitud del array y rellenar el array con numeros aleatorios. 
Una vez creado el array hay que restar el primer valor del array con el ultimo, el segundo con el penultimo y asi sucesivamente. Ya sea par o impar la longitud del array.

Pero no se me ocurren ninguna manera de realizar esto ultimo :(

Lo que tengo hecho:

```
echo 'Array: <br>';

$narray=$_POST['narray'];

for($i=0;$i<$narray;$i++){

    $array[]=rand(0,20);
    echo $array[$i].' | ';

}

echo '<br><br>';
for($i=0;$i<$narray;$i++){

    echo $resta[]=$array[$i]-$array[$narray-1].'|';


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo estas haciendo bien hasta el punto que no coges bien la longitud del `$narray`. La manera de coger la longitud de un array en php es utilizando `count()` que es el equivalente al `.length()` de `js`.

```
$longitud = count($narray);

for($i=0;$i<($longitud/2);$i++){

    echo $resta[]=$array[$i]-$array[($longitud-1) - $i].'|';

}
```

Comment: Sigue sin salirme. Lo que sucede es que solo se restan con el ultimo valor, cuando deberia ser solo el primer valor con el ultimo y luego el segundo valor con el penultimo y asi:   (resultado de ejemplo)                                                                Array: 
1 | 13 | 15 | 8 | 20 | 5 | 9 | 12 | 20 | 13 | 
segundo array
-12 / 0 / 2 / -5/| 7 |

Comment: Tienes razón, me he comido añadir la resta del $i

Comment: Muchas gracias                                                                                        Al final era "simple" pero hasta llegar a ello cuesta. Ahora solo me falta otro ejercicio.

Comment: de nada y suerte con el otro ejercicio.

Answer (score 1):

lo que debes restar debe ir contando de igual manera pero de manera invertida, si por ejemplo tienes un array de longitud 5, en tu primer ciclo estarías restando la posición [longitud -0] (5 ya que tu contador de for inicia en 0) esto es la ultima posición, en tu segundo ciclo del for estarías restando la posición [longitud -1] osea la posición 4 porque ahora tu contador del for vale 1, y así con cada ciclo, solo te faltaría realizar una condición para que lo realiza de la manera que necesitas ya que así como te comenté restarías desde la ultima posición hasta la primera

```
$array[$longitud-$i]
```